# One PHP Variable in Multiple PHP Tag

Tags: php

I have this this PHP tag:

```
<?php 
$date = '2018-09-01';
$end = '2018-09-' . date('t', strtotime($date));
?>
```

and I want to use those two variables inside multiple PHP tag in the same page like this:

**PHP TAG 1**

```
<?php 
   while(strtotime($date) <= strtotime($end)) {
      $day_num = date('d', strtotime($date));
      $day_name = substr(date('l', strtotime($date)), 0, 2);
      $date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($date)));
      echo "<th class='$day_num $day_name'>$day_num <br> <div id='day-name'>$day_name</div>";};
?>
```

**PHP TAG 2**

```
<?php          
   while(strtotime($date) <= strtotime($end)) {
      $day_num = date('d', strtotime($date));
      $day_name = date('l', strtotime($date));
      $date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($date)));
      echo "<td class='$day_num $day_name'><input type='checkbox' class='uk-checkbox'></td>";
        };
?>
```

The problem is that it works in the **PHP TAG 1** and not working in **PHP TAG 2**.

What is the problem that it is showing any output in **PHP TAG 2**.

There is no error shown in console.

Remember that I can't join these two PHP tags because they are separated by another contents in the page.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "it is not working in PHP TAG 2"?

Comment: Can you add more details about `not working`? Does it throw an error, give incorrect output, no output, other?

Comment: You dont need semi-colons attached the end bracket on the while statements.

Comment: You overwrite the `$date` variable in php tag 1 until it is bigger or equal to `$end`, so the loop in php tag 2 will not be executed because the condition is never true. Use another variable than `$date` in your loops or save the initial value before it gets changed and load it before you enter the loop in php tag 2.

Comment: @PhilippMaurer can you explain more.

Comment: If this code is all in the same script. Once you complete TAG1 you have moved the StartDate to match the EndDate. Therefore when you get to TAG2 StartDate is already `>=` EndDate so that loop never runs. Reset the StartDate before TAG2 and it will run

Comment: *"This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error"*. The problem can easily be reproduced and is not created by a simple typographical error. Future readers can learn from the effect, that a variable changed in a loop keeps the last value it had in the loop afterwards. Iam sure there is a duplicate for this, so it should be closed, but it is defineately not off topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your PHP script starts, you set the followng values:

```
<?php 
$date = '2018-09-01';
$end = '2018-09-' . date('t', strtotime($date)); //'2018-09-30'
?>
```

When you code enters PHP tag 1, the `while` loop evaluates the difference between the two dates with `while (strtotime($date) <= strtotime($end))`, which evaluates as true, since `'2018-09-01'` is smaller than `'2018-09-30'`.

Then, while in the loop, your code changes the `$date` vairable until the upper condition is not true anymore. This will happen when `$date` gets set to `'2018-10-01'`. So after leaving PHP tag 1, your variables now hold the following values. They are now the same.

```
$date = '2018-10-01';
$end = '2018-09-30';
```

When entering PHP tag 2, you evaluate the condition in your while loop again, but `while (strtotime($date) <= strtotime($end))` is no longer true. Because of that the second loop is never executed.

---

To solve the problem, save the initial value of `$date` in another variable:

```
<?php
//Start of your script
$date = '2018-09-01';
$end = '2018-09-' . date('t', strtotime($date)); //'2018-09-30'
$start = $date;
?>
```

Then, when you enter PHP tag 2, replace the then wrong `$date` with its initial value which is now saved in `$start`.

```
<?php
$date = $start;
while(strtotime($date) <= strtotime($end)) {
    $day_num = date('d', strtotime($date));
    $day_name = date('l', strtotime($date));
    $date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($date)));
    echo "<td class='$day_num $day_name'><input type='checkbox' class='uk-checkbox'></td>";
};
?>
```

Now the 2nd loop will run exactly as often as the first one.

Comment: Is it possible to assign a global value in a page and use it in any php tags.